# Re-size contents of an iframe without re-sizing the frame itself

Tags: html, css, forms, iframe, formatting

I'am currently hosting a sms poll on my website, through an external service which
provides the results on their webpage. I want to display that webpage on my website.

To do that I'am using iframe:
    iframe src="smspoolwebsite.com" width="700" height="1300" frameborder="1"

The width and the height of the iframe itself cannot be changed in size otherwise my website breaks/doesn't look nice, but the available width is just a little bit not enough.

So I was wondering if there is a way to shrink the contents of the iframe without changing the form itself. I have searched around and solutions such as "webkit-transform
moz-transform" did not seem to work for me since they re-sized the form as well.

Im using Web-Asyst engine, and available tools for me are CSS, and whatever you can use within an HTML file.

I apologize for language, im not a native English speaker if you have any grammar/spelling corrections i will use them. 
Also my html,css etc knowledge is very limited.

Thank you

Comment: What webkit transform methods have you tried? Did you use the `scale(float percentage)`?

Comment: The two things I would offer you to try in some combination are 1. setting the `zoom` property of CSS to something below 1 to scale it down, and 2. setting the `...-transform: scale(percentage)` and `...-transform-origin: 0.0` until it looks the way you want. One or both should accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have tried the scale thing, to be precise i did
-webkit-transform: scale(0.90);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
As a result it decreased the whole frame i will try the zoom thing now

Comment: There's a demonstration of a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dirkk0/EEgTx/show/ Apparently you want to set the width and height of the frame to the width you want times the inverse of the scale, so for instance, if you want to scale it to 90% and have it fill 900px of width, set the width to 1000px, and apply the transform scale and origin properties.